# Techno-Culinary Brain Teaser: Unravel the Code in the Kitchen

Tags: word, visual, no-computers, rebus, computer-puzzle

The answer is one word.

**The rebus:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it is

> Domain, which sounds like dough + main (the 4 letter word missing in the C program)